# Is it possible to enforce standard behavior with Visual Studio 2013 C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, standards

When porting my project to linux using gcc, I've come across quite a few errors that are a result of VS trying to be "convenient" such as using standard functions like "memcpy" and the "str*" functions without needing to include the right headers, or the std::exception::exception overload that takes a const char*. Is there anyway to force VS to not do this along with other non-standard behaviors?

Comment: On the headers thing: that has been going on since forever. BSD includes different headers than Linux than Windows. It comes down to what other headers are pulled in by things like stdio.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. MS has "extensions" like `const char *` for `std::exception`.

You could try setting up a "sanity" build, on say a continuous integration machine to build with another compiler to check.

Do try having the warning level turned all the way up. This may catch one or two things.